# Maven cant compile test-classes when using test scope

Tags: java, maven, testing, minecraft, dependency-management

I am currently trying to use [MockBukkit](https://github.com/seeseemelk/MockBukkit) for testing my Minecraft Plugin and included it in my pom with the test scope because I will only need it for that. The problem is however that when using the test scope, the dependency appears in my local repository but cannot be resolved by eclipse or Maven.

The problem appears to be that the default-compile goal from the [compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) plugin tries to compile the test classes even though it cannot use the dependencies as they are only available during the testing phase. (However that is only my guess).

Maven output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ CityCraft ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 32 source files to C:\Users\lptoa\Desktop\MC Plugins\CityCraft\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[3,32] package be.seeseemelk.mockbukkit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[4,32] package be.seeseemelk.mockbukkit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[9,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ServerMock
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[12,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[19,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class After
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[15,22] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MockBukkit
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[16,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MockBukkit
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lptoa/Desktop/MC Plugins/CityCraft/src/test/java/skyvide/de/city/CityTests.java:[22,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MockBukkit
  location: class test.java.skyvide.de.city.CityTests
```

Location:

```
->src
 --->test
    --->java
      --->example
        --->ExampleTest.java
```

Code:

```
package test.java.example;

import be.seeseemelk.mockbukkit.MockBukkit;
import be.seeseemelk.mockbukkit.ServerMock;
import main.plugin;

public class ExampleTest {
    
    private ServerMock server;
    private Plugin plugin;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        server = MockBukkit.mock();
        plugin = (Plugin) MockBukkit.load(Plugin.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        MockBukkit.unmock();
    }
}
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sv-plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>CityCraft</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testing</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>test.output.dir</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${test.output.dir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>papermc</id>
        <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>everything</id>
        <url>https://repo.citizensnpcs.co/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>aikar</id>
        <url>https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.github.WesJD.AnvilGUI:anvilgui</include>
                            <include>co.aikar:acf-paper</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
    <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.citizensnpcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>citizens</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.27-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>sv-plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySQL</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>sv-plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>Clouds</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.WesJD.AnvilGUI</groupId>
    <artifactId>anvilgui</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>co.aikar</groupId>
    <artifactId>acf-paper</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.seeseemelk</groupId>
    <artifactId>MockBukkit-v1.16</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I doubt that the package name `test.java.example` is correct? Where have you located your tests  in `src/test/java/<packageName>`? Apart from that please show the pom file...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added the POM and the location of the file now =) @khmarbaise

Comment: test dependencies are used to _compile and run_ test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the error was just that I had to change the .classpath because I just converted a default eclipse project to a Maven project, so I had to remove the default src folder in the Build Path and add the different Maven ones. Without it, Maven tried to compile every class as a normal one and not as tests which made them fail.

In case anyone's interested, here is a comparision between the two .classpath files:

Old:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

New:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```